# Issue with While Loop with Nested While loop using SQL Server 2016

Tags: t-sql, while-loop

I am using SQL Server 2016 and getting lost in the weeds using NESTED WHILE LOOPS.
In the INNER WHILE LOOP I'm populating a TEMP table (#tempClaimRecordsForInsert) that holds a PolicyNo and ClaimNo. There are 773 records. The TEMP table gets populated correctly without issue.
The problem is in the OUTER WHILE LOOP where I'm trying to populate another TEMP table where I'm trying to add 773 claims to each UserSysID from the temp table (there are 16 UserSysID records) created in the inner loop. I am NOT getting any records in the TEMP table (#tempRecordsForInsert) with all records.
Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Here is my SQL code:

```
DECLARE @counterUserID int = 1;
DECLARE @counterClaims int = 1;
CREATE TABLE #tempClaimRecordsForInsert (
    PolicyNo varchar(10)
    , ClaimNo varchar(6)
);
CREATE TABLE #tempRecordsForInsert (
    ReinsuranceAuditSysID int
    , PolicyNo varchar(10)
    , ClaimNo varchar(6)
)

WHILE @counterUserID <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tempAuditorUserIdList)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @UserSysID int = (SELECT l.UserSysID FROM #tempAuditorUserIdList l WHERE l.RN = @counterUserID);

        WHILE @counterClaims <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #ClaimNo)
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @RN1 int = (SELECT c.RN FROM #ClaimNo c WHERE c.RN = @counterClaims);

                INSERT INTO #tempClaimRecordsForInsert
                SELECT c.PolicyNo, c.ClaimNo --, x.RN
                FROM dbo.CMS_Claims c
                INNER JOIN #ClaimNo x
                ON c.ClaimNo = x.ClaimNo
                WHERE x.RN = @RN1;

                SET @counterClaims = (@counterClaims + 1)
            END

    INSERT INTO #tempRecordsForInsert
    SELECT @UserSysID as ReinsuranceAuditSysID, i.ClaimNo, i.PolicyNo
    FROM #tempClaimRecordsForInsert i
    WHERE @UserSysID = @counterUserID

    SET @counterUserID = (@counterUserID + 1)
END

SELECT * FROM #tempClaimRecordsForInsert;
DROP TABLE #tempClaimRecordsForInsert;
SELECT * FROM #tempRecordsForInsert;
DROP TABLE #tempRecordsForInsert;
```

Comment: In #tempClaimRecordsForInsert you are only inserting PolicyNo and ClaimNo but you may need the UserSysID to compare against the @countUserID in the outer insert condition

Comment: Jayvee, thanks.  I'll try it. Thanks

Comment: I mean you need something in the #tempClaimRecordsForInsert  to compare against the counter in the outer insert condition, probably UserSysID is the right one

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the table data is difficult to know but if you had UserSysId in the  #tempClaimRecordsForInsert, then the where clause of the outer insert should be:

```
 UserSysID = (SELECT l.UserSysID FROM #tempAuditorUserIdList l WHERE l.RN = @counterUserID)
```

Comment: Jayvee, thanks for taking time to look at this.  The data in the #tempAuditorUserIdList table is a list of INT values in the column UserSysID and you're correct the RN (is the row number) and the UserSysID are not the same. You were correct about your suggestion.  Unfortunately that didn't help me get any results.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: I updated the answer, I think if you manage to bring the usersysid to #tempClaimRecordsForInsert then you can make the where clause for the outer insert as i put it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

@Jayvee, I was finally able to resolve my problem but again thank you for taking time to look at my question.  Below is the code that fixed the issue.  I didn't have to put in @UserSysID into the #tempClaimRecordsForInsert which I was grateful for.  I found the answer stepping through my code using the SSMS Debugger in SQL Server 2016.  Here is the code in the event that someone else has the same issue:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempClaimRecordsForInsert (
    PolicyNo varchar(10)
    , ClaimNo varchar(6)
);
CREATE TABLE #tempRecordsForInsert (
    ReinsuranceAuditSysID int
    , PolicyNo varchar(10)
    , ClaimNo varchar(6)
);

DECLARE @counterUserID int = 1;
DECLARE @counterClaims int = 1;

WHILE @counterUserID <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tempAuditorUserIdList)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @UserSysID int = (SELECT l.UserSysID FROM #tempAuditorUserIdList l WHERE l.RN = @counterUserID);
    
            WHILE @counterClaims <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #ClaimNo)
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE @RN1 int = (SELECT c.RN FROM #ClaimNo c WHERE c.RN = @counterClaims);

                    INSERT INTO #tempClaimRecordsForInsert
                    SELECT c.PolicyNo, c.ClaimNo 
                    FROM dbo.CMS_Claims c
                    INNER JOIN #ClaimNo x
                    ON c.ClaimNo = x.ClaimNo
                    WHERE x.RN = @RN1;

                    SET @counterClaims = (@counterClaims + 1)
                END
                
        INSERT INTO #tempRecordsForInsert
        SELECT @UserSysID as ReinsuranceAuditSysID, i.PolicyNo, i.ClaimNo
        FROM #tempClaimRecordsForInsert i
        WHERE @UserSysID = (SELECT l.UserSysID FROM #tempAuditorUserIdList l WHERE l.RN = @counterUserID)

        SET @counterUserID = (@counterUserID + 1);
    END

SELECT * FROM #tempClaimRecordsForInsert ORDER BY ClaimNo asc;
SELECT * FROM #tempRecordsForInsert ORDER BY ReinsuranceAuditSysID asc, ClaimNo asc;
DROP TABLE #tempClaimRecordsForInsert;
DROP TABLE #tempRecordsForInsert;
```